# SQL Server Regular Expression Workaround in T-SQL?

Tags: regex, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I have some SQLCLR code for working with Regular Expresions. But now that it is getting migrated into Azure, which does not allow SQLCLR, that's out. I need to find a way to do regex in pure T-SQL.

Master Data Services are not available because the dev edition of MSSQL we have is not R2.

All ideas appreciated, thanks.

Regular expression match samples that need handling
(culled from regexlib and other places over the past few years)

email address

```
^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$
```

dollars

```
^(\$)?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*)|([1-9]\d*)|(0))(\.\d{2})?$
```

uri

```
^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$
```

one numeric digit

```
^\d$
```

percentage

```
^-?[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$|^-?(100)(\.[0]{1,2})?$
```

height notation

```
^\d?\d'(\d|1[01])&quot;$
```

numbers between 1 1000

```
^([1-9]|[1-9]\d|1000)$
```

credit card numbers

```
^((4\d{3})|(5[1-5]\d{2})|(6011))-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}|3[4,7]\d{13}$
```

list of years

```
^([1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}[,]?)*([1-9]{1}[0-9]{3})$
```

days of the week

```
^(Sun|Mon|(T(ues|hurs))|Fri)(day|\.)?$|Wed(\.|nesday)?$|Sat(\.|urday)?$|T((ue?)|(hu?r?))\.?$
```

time on 12 hour clock

```
(?<Time>^(?:0?[1-9]:[0-5]|1(?=[012])\d:[0-5])\d(?:[ap]m)?)
```

time on 24 hour clock

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

usa phone numbers

```
^\(?[\d]{3}\)?[\s-]?[\d]{3}[\s-]?[\d]{4}$
```

Comment: If it makes you feel better...http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34685-sql-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/401015-support-clr-stored-procedures?ref=title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to move your CLR function(s) to SQL Azure. You will need to either use the normal string functions (PATINDEX, CHARINDEX, LIKE, and so on) or perform these operations outside of the database.

**EDIT** Adding some information for the examples added to the question.

**Email address**

This one is always controversial because people disagree about which version of the RFC they want to support. The original didn't support apostrophes, for example (or at least people insist that it didn't - I haven't dug it up from the archives and read it myself, admittedly), and it has to be expanded quite often for new TLDs (once for 4-letter TLDs like .info, then again for 6-letter TLDs like .museum). I've often heard quite knowledgeable people state that perfect e-mail validation is impossible, and having previously worked for an e-mail service provider, I can tell you that it was a constantly moving target. But for the simplest approaches, see the question [TSQL Email Validation (without regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229824/tsql-email-validation-without-regex).

**One numeric digit**

Probably the easiest  one of the bunch:

```
WHERE @s LIKE '[0-9]';
```

**Credit card numbers**

Assuming you strip out dashes and spaces, which you should do in any case. Note that this isn't an actual check of the credit card number algorithm to ensure that the number itself is actually valid, just that it conforms to the general format (AmEx = 15 digits starting with a 3, the rest are 16 digits - Visa starts with a 4, MasterCard starts with a 5, Discover starts with 6 and I think there's one that starts with a 7 (though that may just be gift cards of some kind)):

```
WHERE @s + ' ' LIKE '[3-7]'+ REPLICATE('[0-9]', 14) + '[0-9 ]';
```

If you want to be a little more precise at the cost of being long-winded, you can say:

```
WHERE (LEN(@s) = 15 AND @s LIKE '3'     + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 14))
   OR (LEN(@s) = 16 AND @s LIKE '[4-7]' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 15));
```

**USA phone numbers**

Again, assuming you're going to strip out parentheses, dashes and spaces first. Pretty sure a US area code can't start with a 1; if there are other rules, I am not aware of them.

```
WHERE @s LIKE '[2-9]' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 9);
```

**-----**

I'm not going to go further, because a lot of the other expressions you've defined can be extrapolated from the above. Hopefully this gives you a start. You should be able to Google for some of the others to see how other people have replicated the patterns with T-SQL. Some of them (like days of the week) can probably just be checked against a table - seems overkill to do an invasie pattern matching for a set of 7 possible values. Similarly with a list of 1000 numbers or years, these are things that will be much easier (and probably more efficient) to check if the numeric value is in a table rather than convert it to a string and see if it matches some pattern.

I'll state again that a lot of this will be much better if you can cleanse and validate the data before it gets into the database in the first place. You should strive to do this wherever possible, because without CLR, you just can't do powerful RegEx inside SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Ken Henderson wrote about ways to [replicate RegEx without CLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/05/11/416392.aspx), but they require sp_OA* procedures, which are even less likely to ever see the light of day in Azure than CLR. Most of the other articles you'll find online use an approach similar to Ken's or use complex use of built-in string functions.

Which portions of RegEx specifically are you trying to replicate? Can you show an example of the input/output of one of your functions? Perhaps it will be easy to convert to get similar results using the built-in string functions like PATINDEX.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am looking for 'complex use of built-in string functions' since that appears to be my only way out.