# SQL Server - Cast invalid value to int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

Is there any way to deal with SQL casts if the input data is corrupt?

Let's say I have a column of datatype `NVarchar(10)` and want to cast this column to `int`.

Let's also say that some of the `nvarchar` values are corrupt, so they can't be converted to `int`.

Is there any way to silently ignore these, default them to 0 or some such?

Comment: SQL Server **2012** now has `TRY_PARSE`, `TRY_CAST` and `TRY_CONVERT` functions that do exactly what you're looking for. But those are in **2012** (and newer) only.

Comment: Is there any fallback? e.g. a case that matches for numeric first somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Numbers VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
('30a'),('30'),('100'),
('100a'),('200'),('200a')

SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ISNUMERIC(Numbers) = 1 
          THEN CAST(Numbers AS INT) ELSE NULL END AS Number
FROM @t
```

ISNUMERIC Function returns 1 when it is an integer value you can use this function.

**Result**

```
Number
NULL
30
100
NULL
200
NULL
```

it will cast the `integer values to INT and ignore the values that cannot be cast to Int`

Comment: `Isnumeric()` function is not going to work because it will return true for some other characters that are not numbers. Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13171) and [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) link for more details

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` for the most part is useful, but remember that certain values won't get caught by the function.  Sometimes you'll get values with an `e` in the middle, for instance, even though we don't want those values.

Comment: yep I was going to mention this as if you have `e` in your values it sees it as power of that integer left to it. `222e2` is seen as 222^2

Comment: It is not just `e`, please [check this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13172) it has `$ 1` and still `ISNUMERIC()` returning `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this with `PatIndex()` function:

```
select id, val
from t
where  patindex('%[^0-9]%',val) = 0
```

Note: above query is filtering out corrupted values, if you need to bring them in with 0 values, please use a `case expression` as below.

```
select id, case when patindex('%[^0-9]%',val) = 0 
                then convert(int, val) 
           else 0 end val
from t
```

**[Fiddle demo for both queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8c56/3)**

Answer (score 2):

I'll be the unpopular one and advise `REGEX` because `ISNUMERIC`, while sometimes useful, doesn't catch everything.  [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197163/2445226) excellently covers some REGEX concepts, for instance:

> **One numeric digit**
>
> Probably the easiest one of the bunch:
>
> ```
> WHERE Column LIKE '[0-9]'
> ```

For more details, here's a [useful REGEX workbench](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/) by Phil Factor and Robyn Pae.