# SQL select all does not include @ symbol

Tags: sql, select

I tried this but it doesn't work. I want to find all the inputs which do not have a valid e-mail with an @ symbol

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmail
WHERE [email] <> '%@'
```

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801166/sql-script-to-find-invalid-email-addresses

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL Email Validation (without regex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229824/tsql-email-validation-without-regex)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmail WHERE [email] NOT LIKE '%@%'
```

Answer (score 1):

To fully validate an email address using mysql you should do:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblEmail 
 WHERE email NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe using NOT LIKE '%@%'

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where email NOT LIKE '%@%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current query is searching for an `@` symbol at the end of the text only. If you need to match anywhere within the text (which is the case for emails) I expect you need to use `'%@%'`.

Hence your full query might look like

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmail Where [email] NOT LIKE '%@%'
```