# SQL Server : search for Email in String

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working in a SQL Server environment and have a `varchar(100)` column called `AdditionalData`. Sometimes, but not always, this column will contain an email. I need help building a query that only returns rows in which `AdditionalData` has an email address in it.

Comment: I swear SE's community is a bunch of vultures.  Please link the duplicated question.  I made a conscious effort look if I was asking a similar question.

Comment: You should see the link to the question in the blue box above your original text. [Here's another link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229824/tsql-email-validation-without-regex). Also, dont feel as though you are being punished for not finding a duplicate.  Marking duplicates is a way that we help you and others looking for the same or similar answer.  It can get a little overwhelming how fast it all happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the emails contains @:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE AdditionalData LIKE '%@%';
```

Comment: I love SE's way of making me feel stupid.  I searched/over thought this way to much.  Thank you for the simple answer.