# Customer email address

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql programming. This is for a homework assignment for my database class.  I have made all the table I need for the assignment I am just hung up one part. The line in the homework reads as follows:

> If type is 'faculty' the email address must end up with '@xxx.edu'

This is what the table looks like:

```
create table customer
(
CID# char(10) primary key IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
F_name varchar(20),
M_name varchar(20),
L_name varchar(20),
type varchar(20),
street varchar(20),
city varchar(20),
state varchar(20),
zip char(5),
password varchar (20) NOT NULL,
email varchar(20) NOT NULL
Constraint CK_customer_type check (type in ('student', 'faculty'))
)
```

Any help someone could lend would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I think the question is: how to put the constraint for e-mail address column?

Answer (score 1):

This constraint would check if the email column ends with `@xxx.edu`.

```
Constraint CK_email_faculty check (
   type<>'faculty' OR 
   CHARINDEX('@xxx.edu',email)=LEN(email)-LEN('@xxx.edu')+1
)
```

---

Remark 1: Better than checking the type being appropriate in a CHECK constraint, make a table `customer_type` with possible types ('student', 'faculty' ...), and have a foreign key in `customer` pointing a the type.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_type(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,desc VARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO customer_type(id,desc)VALUES(1,'student');
INSERT INTO customer_type(id,desc)VALUES(2,'faculty');
```

Have a foreign key in your `customer` table to point to the `customer_type` table:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
    -- ...
    type INT NOT NULL,
    -- ...
    CONSTRAINT FK_type_customer_type FOREIGN KEY(type) REFERENCES customer_type(id)
)
```

You would then not insert the type description but the type identifier:

```
INSERT INTO customer(...,type,...)VALUES(...,1,...); -- for student
INSERT INTO customer(...,type,...)VALUES(...,3,...); -- fails, type doesn't exist
```

That way you save disk space, and memory when these tables are cached by SQL Server.

---

Remark 2: The widths of your varchar fields are very small. An email address of only 20 characters?

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case a constraint like this might be ok:

```
Constraint CK_customer_email check (
   type <> 'faculty' OR
   email LIKE '%_%@_%.edu'  
   CHARINDEX('@xxx.edu',email)=LEN(email)-LEN('@xxx.edu')+1
)
```

This will allow 1+ characters, followed by @, followed by 1+ characters, followed by `.edu`.

However, in real life (where mean people try to insert bad e-mail addresses), [validation is more complex](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/) (not all characters are allowed), so a custom function can be used. One that seems to be almost complete is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1345539/2780791):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnAppEmailCheck](@email VARCHAR(255))   
--Returns true if the string is a valid email address.  
RETURNS bit  
as  
BEGIN  
     DECLARE @valid bit  
     IF @email IS NOT NULL   
          SET @email = LOWER(@email)  
          SET @valid = 0  
          IF @email like '[a-z,0-9,_,-]%@[a-z,0-9,_,-]%.[a-z][a-z]%'  
             AND LEN(@email) = LEN(dbo.fnAppStripNonEmail(@email))  
             AND @email NOT like '%@%@%'  
             AND CHARINDEX('.@',@email) = 0  
             AND CHARINDEX('..',@email) = 0  
             AND CHARINDEX(',',@email) = 0  
             AND RIGHT(@email,1) between 'a' AND 'z'  
               SET @valid=1  
     RETURN @valid  
END
```

Then, your constraint would be like this:

```
Constraint CK_customer_email check (
   type <> 'faculty' OR
   [dbo].[fnAppEmailCheck] (email) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Constraint

```
Constraint CK_email check (email like case when type in ('faculty') then '%@xxx.edu' else email end )
```